# check data sequence in SQL

Tags: sql

I have weekly data in columns. I need to exclude records where there are continuous null values for four week.

| TempID | Week1 | Week 2 | Week3 | Week4 | Week5 | Week6 | Week7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 4 | 4 |
| 234 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 6 | NULL | 4 | 4 |
| 333 | 4 | NULL | 4 | 8 | NULL | 4 | 4 |

For this example I need to exclude temp id `123`.
And rest need to be included.Basically exclude records where there is four continuous null records in columns.

How I can check the order I described here?

Comment: Something wrong in the tags: you've set Oracle and mysqli which are about different databases. What DBMS is yours? Please, correct tags

Comment: this is SQL Database

Comment: SQL is a language you speak to relational database, but it's dialects are different. Please, check [SQL tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) for more details

Comment: Side note: Fix the schema. You shouldn't have columns for each week but rows.

Answer (score 0):

You may just repeat all the possible sequences in the `where` condition wrapped with`coalesce` function: `coalesce` returns first non-null value, so if it returns null, then all the values are null.

```
select *
from yourtable
where coalesce(week1, week2, week3, week4) is null
  or coalesce(week2, week3, week4, week5) is null
  or coalesce(week3, week4, week5 week6) is null
  or coalesce(week4, week5 week6 week7) is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with four columns out of seven, there are really only 4 combinations to test for:

```
Select * from table
Where 
(week1 is null and week2 is null and week3 is null and week4 is null)
Or 
(week2 is null and week3 is null and week4 is null and week5 is null)
Or
(week3 is null and week4 is null and week5 is null and week6 is null)
Or
(week4 is null and week5 is null and week6 is null and week7 is null)
```